# unverified breakpoint appear in visual studio code debug react native project

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have installed react native tools extension for visual studio code to debug my react native project.
But breakpoints cannot be set (app is successfully lunched), breakpoints appear grey with an `Unverified Breakpoint` note, bunch of errors are displayed.

My software version as below:

> React-Native VS Code extension version: 0.3.2
>
> VSCode version: 1.12.2
>
> OS platform and version: OS X/10.11.6
>
> NodeJS version: v6.10.3
>
> React Native version: 0.44.0
>
> React-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: Having the same issue on my end.

Comment: The following is the chrome console when I toggle developer tool in vscode.
/Users/chenzhiyuan/Downloads/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser/workbench.main.js:29 [Extension Host] (node:5303) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
d.logExtensionHostMessage @ /Users/chenzhiyuan/Downloads/Visual Studio Code -